# What is the difference between a 2D string of the type string[10][20] compared to a 2D string of the type *string [10][20] in C?

Tags: c, string, windows, codeblocks, string.h

I am a beginner in C and I use CodeBlocks for Windows.

I learnt that a string is a sequence of characters (chars) but I needed a sequence of strings.

In a video I saw that if I use a pointer in my string (it was `char string[20][10]` and now it is `char* string[20][10]`) I could print every "space" of the string as a string and not as a `char`. (By space I mean, for example, `string[0][0]`). But then I tried to use `strcpy()` in two of the spaces of that string and the program didn't work. Can anyone tell me why that happened and what does the pointer changes in this kind of strings?

edit: Here is the code that didn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char* array[3][10];
    for(i = 0; i != 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j != 10; j++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                array[i][j] = "ABC";
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                array[i][j] = "DEF";
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
                array[i][j] = "GHI";
            }    
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i != 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j != 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%s", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    strcpy(array[2][0], array[1][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

(This isn't the actual code that I have a question that one is too hard to explain here. But if you still find this question confusing after reading this code, I'll try to explain the original one).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Please provide the code that "didn´t work".

Comment: `char* string[20][10]` is a 2-D array of `char *` and in that case the `string[0][0]` will hold a value of type `char *`. If such a value is used as the second parameter of `strcpy` it needs to point to the first element of a null terminated string. If it is used as the first parameter of `strcpy` it needs to point to a buffer large enough to hold a null terminated string pointed to by the second parameter. If neither is the case, that will explain why it "didn't work".

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm using two values of the type char* in both parameters in strcpy. What exactly is a null terminated string?

Comment: @KazzioBots A null terminated string is an array of `char` (or a block of memory organised like an array of `char`) with a zero-valued `char` element marking the end of the string. The "length" of the null terminated string (as returned by `strlen` is the number of `char`s before the null terminator. When using `strcpy` to copy a null terminated source string to a destination buffer, the destination buffer needs to be large enough to hold the whole string up to and including the null terminator (at least `1+strlen(srcstring)` `char`s long).

Comment: regarding: `char* array[3][10];`   This is declaring (effectively) 30 pointers to char.  Not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249 What do you mean when you say "Not what you want"? Is it because the array is too long and I only need it to be char*  array[3][3], and have 9 pointers to char? Or is it something else?

Comment: the first method you ask about:  `char string[3][10]` will give you 3 slots of 10 bytes each for data.  The second method:  `char* array[3][10];` will give you 30 pointers to data, organized as blocks of 10 pointers in each block.  If you use the second method, they you have to track which pointers are being used and you have to supply each data the selected pointer is pointing toward.   Given the rest of your posted code, The first method seems to be more suited to what you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer your question indirectly, because I think at root what you need to understand is the difference between an array and a pointer.

C can confuse beginners because it uses the same *syntax* for pointers and arrays.  In an array, it defines space for all its elements, and `a[n]` retrieves element `n`.  If `a` is a pointer, it defines space only for the pointer, and `a[n]` refers to the `n`th location starting wherever `a` points.  If `a` is an array, you can still use *pointer syntax* `*(a + n)` to refer to `a[n]`.  For that matter `n[a]` gets you the same thing.

With experience, the syntax is convenient.  For the student, as I said, the use of identical syntax for two concepts can be confusing.

Both concepts make an appearance in `argv` in your `main` procedure:

`int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

What is `argv`?  And what is `argv[0]`?

`argv` is not a string.  It's an array.  An array of what?  Each element (including the first one, of course) is a `char *`, a pointer to a character.  To *one* character.  As it happens, that character may be followed by another, and another, in a ... *string* ... until the NUL character, indicating the terminus.

Each element in `argv` is a fixed size: `sizeof(char*)`.  The length of `argv` is given by `argc`.  The length of each string pointed to by each element is unknown at compile time; that depends on what arguments are passed to your program when it's invoked.

With `argv` in mind, you'll find your definition, `char* array[3][10]`, easier to understand.  You've also declared an array of `char *`.  What you haven't done is what the OS does when it calls `main`: define something for them to point to, and assign their addresses to the pointers.

When working with pointers, always ask, *what is it pointing at*?  Where was the pointer assigned a value, and how was that memory allocated (static, dynamic, or automatic)?  If you're not sure, it's only a matter of time before the system reminds you that it doesn't know, either.

Answer (score 0):

welcome.

Your question is a little confusing.

In C a string is a sequence of chars or bytes with a NULL terminator e.g. the last one is '\0' or NULL or 0.
Thus:

`char string ="ABCDEF";
 char string[7]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '\0'};
 byte string[7]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 0};`

Are more or less the same.

You can have a pointer to the string such as:

`char *ptr = string;`

but don't confuse this with

`char* ptr[7]` as that is an array of pointers to `char` type

Now strcpy will copy all elements until it detects a NULL terminator, so if you have:

```
char string[]= {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0','E', 'F' };
```

it will only copy "ABCD" and then ignore "EF".

I'm not sure why you seem to think that `string[0][0]` is a space in your string.

All that is the first element in your 2 dimensional array, which is 20 by 10.

You could loop through the data by:

```
char *ptr;
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
  ptr = string[i][0];
  //do something with ptr
}
```

Please explain further what it is that you are trying to do.